# retrieve studentinformation in another page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem about retrieving again in another page of student information.

I can view all students using this through model and view:

```html
 public function viewdata()
 {
               $this->db->order_by("Idnumber", "asc");
  $query= $this->db->get('studentinformation');
                return $query->result();
  
 }
```

```html
  <table class=" table table-hover ">
            
               
           <thead>
                             <tr>
                             
                                   <th>ID Number</th>
                                   <th>Firstname</th>
                                   <th>Middlename</th>
                                   <th>Lastname</th>
                                   <th>Sex</th>
                                   
                           </tr>
                      </thead>
    
    
    <?php
       
   foreach($this->model_adminlogin->viewdata() as $row){
                            
                            
                            ?>
    
    
    
    
    <tbody>
          <tr>
                  
                   
                   <td><?php echo $row->Idnumber?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row->Firstname?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row->Middlename?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row->Lastname?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row->Sex ?></td>
                             <td>
                                 <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>
      
                             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   
                

    
     <?php
     }
   
   
                        
        
                         ?>  
   </table>
```

also I can view them every student information using this in model and controller and view:

```html
  function getonerow($id)
 {
  $this->db->where('Id',$id);
  $query=$this->db->get('studentinformation');
  return $query->row();
 }
```

```html
public function viewspecific($id)
 {
       if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
     $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
     $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
     $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
     $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
           $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
           
           $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
           $row=$this->model_adminlogin->getonerow($id);
           $data['r']=$row;
    $this->load->view('individualviewstudent',$data);
        } else{
            redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
        }
        if((!isset($session_data) || $session_data !=TRUE)) {
          
            redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
        }
  
  
 }
```

and view using $r

```html
<label class="z  label-primary">Name:</label> <span class="z">&nbsp; <?php  echo $r -> Firstname." ". $r-> Middlename." ".$r-> Lastname; ?></span><br>
        
             </div>
             <div class="spacesz">
         <label class="z label-primary">Id Number: </label><span class="z">&nbsp;<?php echo $r->Idnumber; ?></span>
             </div>
              <div class="spacesz">
             <label class="z label-primary">Age:</label><span class="z">&nbsp;<?php echo $r-> Age; ?></span>
              </div>
etc.......................................................................................
```

my problem now how can I retrieve again to another view page with that student I click for my updating purpose??  this is my image of the problem -> 
[retrieve in another page of that student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB7CG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the id available in the object `$r`.

```
<?php echo site_url('student/update/'.$r->Id) ?>
```

Place the above code in your Update Student link. Like below:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('student/update/'.$r->Id) ?>">Update Student</a>
```